# Continuity of $L(x,y)\times X\to Y$, $(T,x)\mapsto Tx$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces. Then the map $\varphi: L(X,Y)\times X\to Y$, $(T,x)\mapsto Tx$ is continuous.

Here $L(X,Y)$ of course notes the set of bounded, linear maps $X\to Y$.

I want to proof the continuity using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ criterion.

Let $(T',x')\in L(X,Y)\times X$, and $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrary. We have to find $\delta >0$ such that when ever (for the product metric) $d((T,x),(T',x'))<\delta$, then $\|Tx-T'x'\|<\varepsilon$.

The product metric is given as $d((T,x),(T',x'))=\max\{\|T-T'\|,\|x-x'\|\}$, where we have the supremum norm, and norm on $X$ respectively.

Now letting $\delta=\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2\min\{\|x\|,\|T\|'\}}$, where we assume without loss of generality that the minimum isnt $0$.

Now we have:

$\|Tx-T'x'\|=\|Tx-T'x+T'x-T'x'\|\leq\|Tx-T'x\|+\|T'(x-x')\|$

$=\|(T-T')x\|+\|T'(x-x')\|\leq \|T-T'\|\|x\|+\|T'\|\|x-x'\|\leq \delta\|x\|+\delta T'<\varepsilon$

Where we used some basic facts off the operator norm.

Is this proof correct?
I find it interesting that this is basically the same proof when showing multiplication is continuous.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your definition of $\delta$ there are apostrophes missing and I think you want to use $\max$ instead of $\min$ since your last inequality doesn't necessarily hold otherwise.

Otherwise, looks just fine to me.